# Stick SQL results into one result

Tags: php

I've this table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qSuM.png]

If there is "cislonakupu" twice or more the same, I need to count "cena"*"mnozstvi" for that "cislonakupu" and stick it together.

Any idea how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT cislonakupu, SUM(cena*mnozstvi) as cislonakupuSUM, [yourothercolumns] FROM objednavkyinfo GROUP BY cislonakupu`

Comment: @Sean Actually, it returns only number 1

Comment: what returns only number 1? your query, `cislonakupuSUM`, your variable, something else?? not sure what is returning 1. Do you have some actual php code that you want to share in your question?

Comment: @Sean The query returns it

Comment: but is that in mysql in phpMyAdmin, or in your php code?

Comment: @Sean In my php code. I simply wrote:
echo mysqli_query(" 
SELECT cislonakupu, SUM(cena*mnozstvi) as cislonakupuSUM FROM objednavkyinfo GROUP BY cislonakupu");

and it returns number one only

Comment: That is not how you use `mysqli_query()`. The connection is the first parameter, with the query as the second -> `$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ...[rest of query]");` Then you need to fetch the rows -> `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ echo $row['cislonakupu']." -> ". $row['cislonakupuSUM']."<br />";}`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the summation of one column, you had to use "group by" after "where" and sum() in your select

try this one

i hope it work

```
select cislonakupu, sum(cena)* mnozstvi  as sum, count(cislonakupu)
from obj
group by cislonakupu
having count(cislonakupu)>=2
```

Comment: Why does it returns only number one?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to count at first
but, it had to work. try it and tell me the result